# Forge viewer InstanceTree getNodeType meaning

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I know that the InstanceTree's getNodeType method returns an integer representing the type of node but I do not see an explanation in the docs for what these integers mean. How should I be interpreting the return value of this method?

Answer (score 0):

At the viewer.js file, I see this:

```
NODE_TYPE_ASSEMBLY = 0x0,   // Real world object as assembly of sub-objects
NODE_TYPE_INSERT = 0x1,     // Insert of multiple-instanced object
NODE_TYPE_LAYER = 0x2,      // A layer (specific abstraction collection)
NODE_TYPE_COLLECTION = 0x3, // An abstract collection of objects (e.g. Doors)
NODE_TYPE_COMPOSITE = 0x4,  // A real world object whose internal structure is not relevant to end user
NODE_TYPE_MODEL = 0x5,      // Root of tree representing an entire Model. An aggregate model can contain multiple nested models.
NODE_TYPE_GEOMETRY = 0x6,   // Leaf geometry node
```